# Need Javascript Regex to Remove one "<br>" tag from any number of consecutive "<br>" tags in a string

Tags: javascript, html, regex

For Example:
`"first line<br><br>Second line"` should be replaced with `"first line<br>Second line"`
`"first line<br><br><br>Second line"` should be replaced with `"first line<br><br>Second line"`
and so on...

What I am trying to do is replace all newline characters in a string recieved from textarea  with `<br>` in a string using the regex: `"str.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>')"` but this puts one extra `<br>` tag because when someone is typing in the textarea they press enter twice instead of once for a newline.

Code:

```html
<textarea style="width:200px;height:200px" id="first"></textarea>
<textarea style="width:200px;height:200px;" id="second"></textarea>
<button id="submit">submit</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    const firstTextArea = document.querySelector('#first');
    const secondTextArea = document.querySelector('#second');
    const submitBtn = document.querySelector('#submit')
    submitBtn.addEventListener('click' , function(){
        let str = firstTextArea.value.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>');
        secondTextArea.value = str;
    })

</script>
```

OUTPUT:
[image]

Comment: Regex is the wrong tool for this.

Comment: Use a [`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) and manipulate it using standard DOM methods.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
 /** split the string by the line breaks. Line breaks are returned as empty strings */
 const brokenString = firstTextArea.value.split(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g);
  
 /** remove the empty strings. Then join the other parts back by '<br>' */
 const rejoinedString = brokenString.filter(s => s !== '').join('<br>');
  
 secondTextArea.value = rejoinedString;
```

**Here is an example:**

**Input:**

```
first
second line

third line with spaces



fourth line with spaces
```

**Output**

```
first<br>second line<br>third line with spaces<br>fourth line with spaces
```

I have created this Pen. You can try it out:
https://codepen.io/bisdas/pen/gOzGXMJ

Answer (score 1):

Updated ansWer

```
let str = firstTextArea.value.replace(/[(?:\r\n|\r|\n),]+/g, '<br>');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/FireAnt121/ts1qyLm9/3/

Comment: What if user presses enter multiple times resulting in three or more <br> tags...

Comment: Can you try this one 
`your_value.replace(/[<br>,]+/g, "<br>")`

Comment: "fi<br>st line
second line" 
this is what i get in the second textarea

Comment: This works in single line `let str = firstTextArea.value.replace(/[(?:\r\n|\r|\n),]+/g, '<br>');`